# WooCommerce Free Shipping Disappears for Cart Values Over €100

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

I'm experiencing a peculiar issue with my WooCommerce setup, where I have configured free shipping to be available for orders equal to or exceeding 80€. However, as soon as the order total surpasses 100€, the free shipping option unexpectedly disappears from the checkout options. This behavior is not intended, and I've been unable to resolve it through regular troubleshooting.

### Environment:

WordPress version: 6.4.3
WooCommerce version: 8.6.1
Germanized for WooCommerce: 3.15.6
Germanized for WooCommerce Pro version: 3.10.0

### Configuration:

Free shipping is set up to be available for orders of 80€ or more.
No other shipping methods conflict with these settings, to my knowledge.
I have tried deactivating other plugins to check for conflicts but the issue persists.
Steps to Reproduce:

Add products to the cart that total between 80€ and 99€. The free shipping option appears as expected.
Increase the cart value to over 100€. The free shipping option disappears from the checkout page.

### Attempts to Fix:

Checked for any conditional shipping rules that might affect orders over 100€.
Reviewed the settings in both WooCommerce and the Germanized Pro plugin to ensure there's no unintended configuration causing this.
Searched through the WooCommerce and Germanized documentation and forums for similar issues.
Question:
Has anyone encountered a similar issue or does anyone have insights into what might be causing this problem? Are there known compatibility issues between WooCommerce's shipping options and the Germanized for WooCommerce Pro plugin that could lead to this behavior? Any suggestions for debugging or resolving this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

I'm selling in Sweden so I am using SEK as currency and when the order surpasses 500 its free, as it should. When over 1000 it's back to standard shipping again.

I solved this by setting additional free shipping rules. Over 1000, 2000, 3000 so forth.

You could do the same thing using 100s instead of 1000s.